# Show dates with century to avoid confusion

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface

I was doing a bit of clean up and got confused over a post that clearly belonged on meta, seemed to have been closed and reopened, and appeared to have been asked recently.  Then I noticed that the date was Aug 10 08 at ..., not Aug 10 at ....  I guess I've just gotten used to looking at the month and day.  Adding the century would make the year more obvious.  And you won't have to change it when the next century rolls over.  No Y2.1K bug... :-)

Answer (score 5):

If I had my druthers, all dates would be `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: I always do this with log files, exports, etc. so that they're sortable, except I omit the dashes.  Drives my users crazy though until I explain it to them that it's really better this way.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

We had it this way originally and changed it; makes the text almost too long to fit in the box, and looks bad visually.

Edit: we now add a tick, like so  --

Aug 12 '08 at 13:45

Comment: Please reconsider doing an adjustment to it.  I didn't find this post until tvanfosson pointed it out, so I made a dupe here with my suggestions, perhaps one of them would fit better?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/fix-up-the-date-display-a-bit-for-old-questions

Comment: Please, it is an internationnal standard called ISO 8601. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601. It is way easier to read and avoid confusion for month placement between us and european way. That's why there is such a standard