# Fix up the date display a bit for old questions

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, markdown, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show dates with century to avoid confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14655/show-dates-with-century-to-avoid-confusion)

Questions that are older than 1 year are showing their date stamps as something like

```
Aug 12 08 at 20:48
```

It's hard to grok (at least for my poor eyes), especially with the default font and color on SO, where the 12 and the 08 appear quite close together.  Could we get a separator in there?  Maybe

```
Aug 12/08 at 20:48
```

or

```
Aug 12, 2008 at 20:48
```

Comment: or: 12 Aug 2008 at 20:48

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14655/show-dates-with-century-to-avoid-confusion